# EditText focusing Issue..!

Tags: android

In my app, I am using the edit text(text box) which contains some text by default. The problem with the text box is that when the text box is focused the cursor appears at the starting of the string, It does not appear at the end of the string, This  case is happening only in   Nexus S device, I tried it in some other deices like Mile-Stone and nexus, for those devices the cursor appears at the end of the string then why only in Nexus S it shows like this?? Can we control the cursor position in text box??

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittext);    
et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
```